# Writing 404 Error Page Route with Rack Static Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rack, middleware

How do you map a 404 Error Page in the config.ru file o a Rack Static Page (hosted on heroku)?

So far I have this in my config.ru file

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/css", "/images", "/fonts", "/js", "/robots.txt"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if env["PATH_INFO"] =~ /^\/poller/
  [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Hello, World!"]]
else
  [404, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Not Found"]]
end
```

How can I achieve that with Rack? Please share any links you have that I can use to learn more advance things on Rack. I didn't really find the basic links from the gem helpful.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `Rack::Builder`, it will automatically throw 404 for not mapped URLs:

```
app = Rack::Builder.new do

  map '/poller' do

    use Rack::Static,
      :urls => ["/css", "/images", "/fonts", "/js", "/robots.txt"],
      :root => "public"

    run lambda { |env|
      [
        200, 
        {
          'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
          'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
        },
        File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
      ]
    }
  end

end.to_app

run app
```